# asp.net mvc-5 HttpPostedFileBase is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, httppostedfilebase

i am messing around with file uploading using asp.net mvc-5 `HttpPostedFileBase` but it is showing me HttpPostedFileBase is null after i am selecting the image

here is my code

```
 <input type="file" title="search image" file-model="profileimage" id="allfilepath" name="file" />
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
 </button>
```

and my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult insert(HttpPostedFileBase file, quotationcompany quotecomp)
    {
        var allowedExtensions = new[] {
        ".Jpg", ".png", ".jpg", "jpeg"
    };
        if (file == null)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Please Select Image";
            return View();
        }
        else {
            ViewBag.message = "Image Uploaded Successfully";
            return View();
        }

    }
```

> if (file == null)(on this line (`file`) is showing me null after i am uploading png image)

what is wrong in this code?

Comment: An advice! Please use [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HttpPostedFileBase+is+null) before posting duplicate questions otherwise your question can get down votes (*As you already has 9 questions*) and  this might cause you [Question Ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Check Form Attributes

A common mistake people make is missing the following part in the form tag:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Also in MVC your form structure could look something like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "myForm", @role="form" }))
```

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is the right value to enable file upload support for HTML.

Comment: Right you are. Edited. Apologies.